# How to pass "this" context to an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to build autocomplete for some input fields with DevBridge Autocomplete famous plugin/library (not sure what the exact term is).

My common problem is that I lose "this" context when entering the function that should determine what parameter to send (which is now a simple alert($(this).attr('class')) to check the context)

I need to pass an argument to my backend to know which input is the current one beeing treated.

My selector is on an input html looking like that:

```
<input type="text" class="input_actu input_autocomplete" id="input_contentactualites0" name"input_contentactualites0" data-id="" value="" size="70" maxlength="300"/>
```

For now it looks like this:

```
  $('.input_autocomplete').devbridgeAutocomplete({
  serviceUrl: 'autocomplete',
  params: {
    flag: function() {
      alert($(this).attr('class'));
    }
  },
  minChars: 3,
  type: 'post',
  onSelect: function(suggestion) {
    $(this).attr("data-id", suggestion.data)
   }
  });
```

There are plenty of posts and solutions about this problem, I've tried the .bind(this) like that :

```
    $('.input_autocomplete').devbridgeAutocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'autocomplete',
        params: {flag: function () {
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
    }.bind(this)},
        minChars: 3,
        type: 'post',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            $(this).attr("data-id", suggestion.data)
        }
});
```

And it doesn't seem to work, I've also read about call() but I'm not sure if it can work in my case.

Also I would rather not use a Global as it's not the good way to do it.

Any advice is very welcome, thanks for your time reading and helping :)

Comment: method 1 ... `bind` - method 2 - `arrow` - though, you seem to `bind` ... so, any errors you can report from the console? what is the `this` you are binding though? it's not clear from your code

Comment: Console is clear from any errors. I added my selector target in my original post.       

At least I know my syntax is not wrong, I'm keeping investigating and going to try the arrow one, will update if I find the answer thanks

Comment: I first messup with my second code block, it's now the good one

Comment: hello , not is clear. params is optional and how to fire the event params.flag?

Comment: I don't understand sorry, params is indeed optional. I can see it beeing sent in the header of the autocomplete post.

Comment: I update the code, i beelive that you need know the control input onSelect event?

Comment: I have trouble understanding your answer sorry, I gonna try it out but you may have not understand what I want to do.

I wanted "params: " to have a value that would depend on the class of the DOM element my selector is on. The problem is I Iose "this" context when in the params: function().

You are maybe answering my question but can't understand your answer, yet thanks a lot for your time helping :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this help ?

```
    var params = {
        flags: function (o) {
            alert($(o).attr('class'));
        }
    };

    var config = {
        serviceUrl: 'autocomplete',
        minChars: 3,
        type: 'post',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {

            $(this).attr("data-id", suggestion.data);
            //#####################Fire the event:
              params.flags(this);
        }
    };

    var configDev = $.extend(config, params);


    $('.input_autocomplete').devbridgeAutocomplete(configDev);
```

Comment: Thanks except I lose this in the params flag function not in onSelect, also I'm trying not to use this way as people says it's bad.

But thanks I gonna use it if I can't manage to get it properly working

Comment: Please add at least a short description of what the actual fix is.   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers